# How to get the extract the Time zone from systemTimeZone(NSTimeZone)

Tags: iphone, ipad, nstimezone

can any one get me the idea in extracting the Time zone from systemTimeZone(NSTimeZone)

i have added the sample along with this.

```
NSTimeZone *localTime = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
    NSLog(@" - current  local timezone  is  %@",localTime);
```

***Im getting Out put as follows***
*- current  local timezone  is  Asia/Kolkata (GMT+05:30) offset 19800*

From above out put how to get the zone alone .ie- only Asia/Kolkata

Please help me out in this.

Thanks in advance...
Siva

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can get that by `[localTime name];` i guess...

Comment: thanks but i want to convert and get the place alone.can you get some sample

Comment: ya i have tried ,thanks it shows name.but can u let me know,how to convert the NSTime zone to NSString so that i can display it ,it was showing in the log ,